# Get all attributes of an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am trying to go through an element and get all the attributes of that element to output them, for example an  tag may have 3 or more attributes, unknown to me and I need to get the names and values of these attributes. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```js
$(this).attr().each(function(index, element) {
    var name = $(this).name;
    var value = $(this).value;
    //Do something with name and value...
});
```

Could anyone tell me if this is even possible, and if so what the correct syntax would be?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

The `attributes` property contains them all:

```
$(this).each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
    if(this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name, this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

---

What you can also do is extending `.attr` so that you can call it like `.attr()` to get a plain object of all attributes:

```
(function(old) {
  $.fn.attr = function() {
    if(arguments.length === 0) {
      if(this.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      var obj = {};
      $.each(this[0].attributes, function() {
        if(this.specified) {
          obj[this.name] = this.value;
        }
      });
      return obj;
    }

    return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})($.fn.attr);
```

Usage:

```
var $div = $("<div data-a='1' id='b'>");
$div.attr();  // { "data-a": "1", "id": "b" }
```

Comment: You may want to fix it when there's no matched elements e.g. `$().attr()`

Comment: The `attributes` collection contains all possible attributes in older IE, not just those that have been specified in the HTML. You can work around this by filtering the attributes list using each attributes `specified` property.

Comment: This is a very good and expected functionality for jQuery `.attr()` method. It's strange jQuery does not include it.

Comment: just a bit curious to know that why we are accessing it as an array in  `this[0].attributes`?

Comment: `attributes` is not an Array though... in Chrome at least it's a `NamedNodeMap`, which is an Object.

Comment: For the record, while ancient IE versions did list all possible attributes, IE7 was the last version affected by that issue. These days, there is no need to filter the `attributes` list with the `specified` property.

Comment: Mar 2020.  A bit has changed, on Chrome at least.  this.specified is now true for any classes as well as custom attributes...

Answer (score 31):

Here is an overview of the many ways that can be done, for my own reference as well as yours :) The functions return a hash of attribute names and their values.

**Vanilla JS**:

```
function getAttributes ( node ) {
    var i,
        attributeNodes = node.attributes,
        length = attributeNodes.length,
        attrs = {};

    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) attrs[attributeNodes[i].name] = attributeNodes[i].value;
    return attrs;
}
```

**Vanilla JS with Array.reduce**

Works for browsers supporting ES 5.1 (2011). Requires IE9+, does not work in IE8.

```
function getAttributes ( node ) {
    var attributeNodeArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( node.attributes );

    return attributeNodeArray.reduce( function ( attrs, attribute ) {
        attrs[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
        return attrs;
    }, {} );
}
```

**jQuery**

This function expects a jQuery object, not a DOM element.

```
function getAttributes ( $node ) {
    var attrs = {};
    $.each( $node[0].attributes, function ( index, attribute ) {
        attrs[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    } );

    return attrs;
}
```

**Underscore**

Also works for lodash.

```
function getAttributes ( node ) {
    return _.reduce( node.attributes, function ( attrs, attribute ) {
        attrs[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
        return attrs;
    }, {} );
}
```

**lodash**

Is even more concise than the Underscore version, but only works for lodash, not for Underscore. Requires IE9+, is buggy in IE8. Kudos to @AlJey [for that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946982/508355).

```
function getAttributes ( node ) {
    return _.transform( node.attributes, function ( attrs, attribute ) {
        attrs[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    }, {} );
}
```

**Test page**

At JS Bin, there is a [live test page](http://jsbin.com/vefiku/7) covering all these functions. The test includes boolean attributes (`hidden`) and enumerated attributes (`contenteditable=""`).

Answer (score 4):

A debugging script   (jquery solution based on the answer above by hashchange)

```
function getAttributes ( $node ) {
      $.each( $node[0].attributes, function ( index, attribute ) {
      console.log(attribute.name+':'+attribute.value);
   } );
}

getAttributes($(this));  // find out what attributes are available
```

Answer (score 3):

with LoDash you could simply do this:

```
_.transform(this.attributes, function (result, item) {
  item.specified && (result[item.name] = item.value);
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner for you.

### JQuery Users:

Replace `$jQueryObject` with your jQuery object. i.e `$('div')`.

```
Object.values($jQueryObject.get(0).attributes).map(attr => console.log(`${attr.name + ' : ' + attr.value}`));
```

### Vanilla Javascript Users:

Replace `$domElement` with your HTML DOM selector. i.e `document.getElementById('demo')`.

```
Object.values($domElement.attributes).map(attr => console.log(`${attr.name + ' : ' + attr.value}`));
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript function it is easier to get all the attributes of an element in NamedArrayFormat.

```js
$("#myTestDiv").click(function(){
  var attrs = document.getElementById("myTestDiv").attributes;
  $.each(attrs,function(i,elem){
    $("#attrs").html(    $("#attrs").html()+"<br><b>"+elem.name+"</b>:<i>"+elem.value+"</i>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTestDiv" ekind="div" etype="text" name="stack">
click This
</div>
<div id="attrs">Attributes are <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution by Underscore.js**

For example: Get all links text who's parents have class `someClass`

```
_.pluck($('.someClass').find('a'), 'text');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htfL3d4g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
$.fn.attrs = function (fnc) {
    var obj = {};
    $.each(this[0].attributes, function() {
        if(this.name == 'value') return; // Avoid someone (optional)
        if(this.specified) obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

var a = $(el).attrs();