# Cycle through all descendants of an element, get their attributes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html block, that contains a lot of children.

```
<div id="selectedId">
    <div class=".."><a class=".."></a>
        <button style=".."></button>
    </div>
    <div id="otherId">
        <table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to select the parent. I am then trying to loop over all the descendants and access various properties, such as class or innerHtml. I seem unable to access their properties.

```
function rewriteCategoryName(oldCategoryName, newCategoryName)
{
    // get div parent
    var parentDiv = $("#selectedId");   

    parentDiv.find('*').each( function(el,key) {
        alert(el+" --");
        el.each( function(el,key) {
           // i get just numbers here, and undefined on everything 
           // i try to access
        });

    });
}
```

Any ideas? What am i doing wrong here? Is there a concept that i am missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: What about `$('.oldClassName').removeClass('oldClassName').addClass('newClassName');`

Comment: Maybe you should use a template: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectedId").find('*').each( function(el,key) {

    $(this).each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function() {
        // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
        // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
        if(this.specified) {
          console.log(this.name, this.value);
        }
      });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've switched the order in the each function, the key is the first parameter and the element is the second, so change:

```
$("#selectedId").find('*').each( function(el,key)
```

to:

```
$("#selectedId").find('*').each( function(key,el) {
```

for more details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Yes, i had noticed. Thank you very much!