# jQuery select when attribute NAME starting with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I want to remove all attributes with name starting `data-val-range`.

I.e. from the following element I wanna remove the matching attributes:

```
<input data-val-range-min="*" data-val-range-max="$" data-val-range="hallelujah"/>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the attribute from the element, or do you need to remove it from jQuery's cache as well?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it enough removing from the element, I need to disable those attributes, I don't actually care how its done.

Comment: Possibly, it depends on your implementation. If you only remove it from the element it would still exist in jQuerys cache - whether that has any effect would depend on how and when you use the data attributes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So how can I disable the validation for element?

Comment: How are the validation rules being set? It may be the case that removing the attributes after the validation initialised has no effect.

Comment: Are you including any jquery-validation.js file in your page??

Comment: I am. The problem is I'm using `RangeAttribute` for a `DateTime` field and the jquery validation keeps on complaining about invalid date, while it's actually valid, so I want to disable it.

Comment: I wrote a little bit complex solution: http://jsfiddle.net/n43g7e9o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery), You can just iterate through the attributes, and remove them according to the name...

Your javascript should be something like

```
$("input").each(function() {
  var theElem=this;
    $.each(this.attributes,function() { 
      if(this.specified) {     
        if(this.name.indexOf("data-val-range")>-1) {
          console.log("removing ",this.name);
          $(theElem).removeAttr(this.name); 
        }                                                     
      }
    })
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dkusds1s/