# Find All Data Attributes on a Single Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know a quick and efficient way to grab all the data attributes from a single element? I realize that jQuerys .data() will do just that, however it will not give me data attributes set using .attr() UNLESS I first select the data attribute using .data(); Also, you can't select elements by data attributes that were added using .data(), which seems silly.

html

```
<div data-foo="bar"></div>
```

javascript

```
$("div").data();
//returns {foo:bar} good :)

$("div").attr("data-hello","world");
$("div").data()
//returns {foo:bar} no good :(

$("div[data-hello]");
//returns the div, all good :)

$("div").data("find","me");
$("div[data-find]");
//returns nothing, very bad
```

Hopefully this explains

Comment: can you give us an example to give some context/reference to?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery) maybe helpful.

Comment: `domElement.dataset`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility) property in modern browsers(IE11+ only), but you can enhance the solution to use [.attributes](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mdn%20element%20attributes) to support older browsers

```
var $in = $('input'),
    input = $in[0], //here input is a dom element reference
    dataMap = input.dataset;
//if dataset is not supported
if (typeof dataMap == 'undefined') {
    dataMap = {};
    $.each(input.attributes, function (key, attr) {
        var match = attr.name.match(/^data-(.+)/);
        if (match) {
            dataMap[match[0]] = attr.value;
        }
    })
}
$.each(dataMap, function (key, value) {
    console.log(key, value)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6xqwtws6/)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I would love to use this if it had better support, it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5):

Different versions of Internet Explorer support different features that are relevant to this issue. In version 11, support for `dataset` was added, which returns a *DOMStringMap* of data-attribute names (minus the "data-" portion), and their respective values.

In versions 9 and 10, we can leverage *Array.prototype.slice* to convert the well-supported `attributes` collection into an array that we can then reduce to an object, similar to *DOMStringMap*.

We can combine both of these approaches into a single function that accepts an element as its argument, and returns an object like this *{ name: "pat", "age": 23 }* for all *data-* attributes:

```
function getDataAttributes ( el ) {
    return el.dataset || [].slice.call( el.attributes ).reduce(function ( o, a ) {
        return /^data-/.test( a.name ) && ( o[ a.name.substr( 5 ) ] = a.value ), o;
    }, {} );
}
```

If you require support for Internet Explorer 8, or below, you can still use the above approaches, and simply polyfill [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill).