# How to get list of data attributes in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the total number of data attributes with names in HTML using JavaScript or jQuery? Then, how can I get the data attributes list? Below is my HTML page.

```
  <body>
    <form id="form1" >
    <div id="divid">
        <button onclick="compare();">Compare</button><br />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>         
             <td><h4>Title</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="t2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>         
            <td><h4>Page Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="p1">fgfgg</div></td>
             <td><h4>Page Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="p2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>         
            <td><h4>Description</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="d1">fgfgg</div></td>
             <td><h4>Description</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="d2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>         
            <td><h4>Guide Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="g1">fgfgg</div></td>
             <td><h4>Guide Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="g2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If you're asking about all els containing a given data-attribute, the answers below look pretty solid. If you are looking for all data-* attributes on a given el, then maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746615/find-all-data-attributes-on-a-single-element -- the first answer is pretty comprehensive for that.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the `data` attributes you want to find are placed in the DOM when the page loads, you can use the `attribute` selector to retrieve the elements which have them:

```js
var $elements = $('[data-pccompare');

console.log($elements.length);
```

```css
table td div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="t2">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4>Page Name</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="p1">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Page Name</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="p2">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4>Description</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="d1">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Description</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="d2">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4>Guide Name</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="g1">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Guide Name</h4>
      <div data-pccompare="g2">fgfgg</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access attributes with `'[attribute-name]'` selector

```js
console.log($('[data-pccompare]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" >
    <div id="divid">
        <button onclick="compare();">Compare</button><br />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>         
             <td><h4>Title</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="t2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>         
            <td><h4>Page Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="p1">fgfgg</div></td>
             <td><h4>Page Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="p2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>         
            <td><h4>Description</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="d1">fgfgg</div></td>
             <td><h4>Description</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="d2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>         
            <td><h4>Guide Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="g1">fgfgg</div></td>
             <td><h4>Guide Name</h4><div style="border: 1px solid black;" data-pccompare="g2">fgfgg</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: but i want data attributes list dynamically

Comment: yes you can parse list returned by the query and get elements or properties of those objects