# Can i get all attributes that begin with "on" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to get all the attributes of an element that begins with "on" using jQuery or Vanilla JS. I am currently getting **all** attributes and then looping through them to get the ones I want using the method proposed by @primvdb on this post: [Get all attributes of an element using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery).

My code looks like this:

```js
/* Expanding .attr as proposed by @primvdb */
(function(old) {
  $.fn.attr = function() {
    if(arguments.length === 0) {
      if(this.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      var obj = {};
      $.each(this[0].attributes, function() {
        if(this.specified) {
          obj[this.name] = this.value;
        }
      });
      return obj;
    }

    return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})($.fn.attr);

/* And then my function */
$.fn.attrThatBeginWith = function(begins){
  var attributes = this.attr();
  var attrThatBegin = {};
  for(var attr in attributes){
    if(attr.indexOf(begins)==0){
      attrThatBegin[attr] = attributes[attr];  
    }
  }
  return attrThatBegin;
};

/* Usage */
var onAttributes = $("#MyElement").attrThatBeginWith("on");
```

And this works but is very "dirty". It's seems like with all the vast features of jQuery there should be a better "cleaner" way to do this. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you need this? You can get all the native attributes, but not neccessarely everything jQuery supports, as `on()` can handle custom events etc. as well.

Comment: I need to know what "on" attributes an element has. If the HTML has an unsupported "on" attribute that's not my concern.

Comment: If it works, it's probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Also -> https://jsfiddle.net/yvs7uczx/

Comment: That's great, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all attributes attached to an element with `element.attributes`.
The native attributes object can be converted to an array and then filtered based on the given string.

A plugin that does the above would look like

```
$.fn.attrThatBeginWith = function(begins){
    return [].slice.call(this.get(0).attributes).filter(function(attr) {
        return attr && attr.name && attr.name.indexOf(begins) === 0
    });
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/yvs7uczx/1/)

Comment: This is good except I was hoping it could be an Object and not an Array.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want an object, but you can just make one -> https://jsfiddle.net/yvs7uczx/2/