# Is it possible to select element by attribute value only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find all elements in a page by attribute `value` only (ignoring the key) using jquery.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Currently, I am just iterating on all elements in the page, on every property etc..

Comment: Do you have some of your code?

Comment: Have you tried with some of code?? please share..

Comment: $("*").filter(function() { return $(this).val() == "your_value" }) some thing like that ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/ You can choose the attribute only. Value only means bad performance in any case, since you have to loop all attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.expr`, `Element.attributes`, `Array.prototype.some()`

```js
$.expr[":"].attrValue = function(el, idx, selector) {
  return [].some.call(el.attributes, function(attr) {
    return attr.value === selector[selector.length - 1]
  })
};
// filter element having attribute with `value` set to `"abc"`
$(":attrValue(abc)").css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div title="abc">abc</div>
<div title="def">def</div>
<div title="ghi">ghi</div>
<div title="jkl">jkl</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define new function take as parameter the value you want to filter with (e.g `get_elements_by_value(filter)`), then inside this function parse all the elements of the page using `$('*').each()`, after that parse the attributes of every element `el` of those elements using attribute `attributes` like below :

```
$.each(el.attributes, function(){ })
```

Then inside the `each` loop you could make your condition and push the matched values with the passed `filter` inside `matched[]` that should be returned.

Check working example below, hope this helps.

```js
function get_elements_by_value(filter){
  var matched=[];

  $('*').each(function(index,el) {
    $.each(el.attributes, function() {
      if( this.value===filter )
        matched.push(el);
    })
  })
  return $(matched);
}

get_elements_by_value('my_value').css('background-color','green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="my_value">AA</div>
<div title="def">BB</div>
<input type='text' name='my_value' value='CC'/>
<p class='my_value'>DD</p>
<span title="test">EE</span>
```

Comment: First example would be name of attribute, yes?

Comment: Why include the asterix at all? `$('[value]')` does exactly the same, surely?

Comment: OP appears to be attempting to retrieve element by attribute value instead of attribute name. First example retrieves elements by attribute name?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki _"I need to find all elements in a page by attribute `value` only (ignoring the key)"_

Comment: What he mean by _ignoring the key_?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki _"What he mean by ignoring the key?"_ Ignore `title`, or attribute `.name` at  `<div title="abc">abc</div>` , filter for `"abc"` only. `title` could be anything; e.g., `titles`, `q`, `rst`, etc.

Comment: `:contains()` could also match `.textContent`, `.innerHTML` of element. Note, `$("[value]")` matches "key" or `.name` property of `attributes`, not `.value` property of `attributes`

Comment: `:contains` is for text, not value of inputs or attributes

Comment: Probably because not answering question

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets `[]`

```
var ElementsWithAttributeKeyTest = $('[attributeKey="Test"]');
```

Or pass an object with the attribute name and value as parameter to this function:

```js
var getElemsByAttribute = function(obj) {
  if (obj) {
    if (obj.attributeKey && obj.attributeValue) {
      return $('[' + obj.attributeKey + '="' + obj.attributeValue + '"]');
    }
  }
}

var attrObj = {
  attributeKey: 'data-color',
  attributeValue: 'red'
}
getElemsByAttribute(attrObj).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span data-color="red">Red</span>
<span data-color="red">Red</span>
<span data-color="green">Green</span>
<span data-color="blue">Blue</span>
<span data-color="red">Red</span>
<span data-color="green">Green</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all attributes values you can use this small plugin:

```
$.fn.search_by_attr_value = function(regex) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        var found = false;
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            if (this.specified && this.value.match(regex)) {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
       });
       return found;  
    });
};
```

and you can use it like this:

```
$('*').search_by_attr_value(/^some value$/);
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/387194)

Comment: What is purpose of `this.specified`?

Comment: @guest271314 as in comment in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/387194) The attributes collection contains all possible attributes in older IE, not just those that have been specified in the HTML. You can work around this by filtering the attributes list using each attributes specified property

Comment: Was not aware of `.specified` property at `attributes`