# how get the allclass name with in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How  to get the all class name with in tag, I want get class name one and two, Any one please help me

```
<div id="svgcanvas" style="position:relative">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$('#svgcanvas').children()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get that using JQUERY `.html()` method.

```
$('#svgcanvas').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use id of element along with attribute selector for div to target all the div elements inside `#svgcanvas`

```
$('#svgcanvas div')
```

iterate over the set of returned elements. inside each iteration, iterate over the attributes of that element as shown in this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/1719752):

```
$('#svgcanvas div').each(function(){
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
   // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
   // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
   if(this.specified) {
     console.log(this.name, this.value);
   }
  });
});
```

```js
$('#svgcanvas div').each(function(){
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
   // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
   // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
   if(this.specified) {
     console.log(this.name +"-"+ this.value);
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgcanvas" style="position:relative">
  <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
        $('#svgcanvas').each(function() {
          $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
            // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
              console.log(this.name, this.value);
            }
          });
        });
```