# jQuery, get tag attributes and assign them to a variable

Tags: jquery

How do I add the attributes of a tag to a variable so I can insert them elsewhere?

So an input tag  should assign a variable:

```
tags = { 'type' : 'submit' , 'id' : 'submit' };
```

I know you can ADD attributes using `.attr()`, but something like

```
testMe = $("#submit").attr();
```

Does not work.

Comment: remove `testMe = ` and put something in `attr()`

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/3611180

Comment: I want to add all the attributes already assigned to the input to the variable. So I am trying to fetch the attributes and put them into a variable rather than trying to add the attributes to the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all attributes by looping through `element.attributes` like :

```
$.each(document.getElementById("submit").attributes, function() {
    tags[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var tags = {};

$.each(document.getElementById("submit").attributes, function() {
    tags[this.name] = this.value;
});

console.log(tags);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a node's attributes to an object using:

```
var obj = {};
Array.from(node.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
  obj[attr.name] = attr.value;
});
```

In jQuery, you can do the mapping via [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map):

```
$(..selector..).map(function () {
  var obj = {};
  $.each(this.attributes, function () {
    obj[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  return obj;
});
```

What you'll end up with is a collection of objects that contain the attributes for each node.

You can then use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to access the attributes for an individual node.