# loop over dom element to get attributes value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of DOM elements and want to loop over this and get the data-attribute values for each of these element nodes.

```
[
  <div class=​"something" data-prod-name=​"a" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand=​"ABC" data-product-id=​"137427">​</div>​,
  <div class=​"something" data-prod-name=​"b" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand=​"ABC" data-product-id=​"128830"></div>​,
  <div class=​"something" data-prod-name=​"c" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand=​"ABC" data-product-id=​"128827">​</div>​,
  <div class=​"something" data-prod-name=​"d" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand=​"ABC" data-product-id=​"128824">​</div>
]
```

I tried getting the values like `$('.something')[0].attributes()`, but it did not work. Can anyone help me in getting the desired result?

Thanks in advance :)

EditJustification:
 My question is different as I wanted a simple solution and the the question marked by @madalin as a solution/possible duplicate was not clear but making the things more complicated to understand. @samir advised me the simplest solution. Thanks @samir.

Comment: you can use `.each()` function.

Comment: I'd rather use [dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), if your target platforms allow it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all attributes of an element using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.something').each(function(){
       var dataProdName = $(this).attr('data-prod-name');
       alert(dataProdName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Samir for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `data()`

```js
    $('.something').each(function() {
      var data = $(this).data();
      $('body').append('<div>' +
        " brand: " + data.brand +
        " categoryName: " + data.categoryName +
        " prodName: " + data.prodName +
        " productId: " + data.productId);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something" data-prod-name="a" data-category-name="b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id="137427"></div>
<div class="something" data-prod-name="b" data-category-name="b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id="128830"></div>
<div class="something" data-prod-name="c" data-category-name="b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id="128827"></div>
<div class="something" data-prod-name="d" data-category-name="b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id="128824"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `attributes` property to get all the attributes

```
$('.something').each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i,v) {
    console.log(v);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.data()` reads data attributes:

```
$(".something").each(function(i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    console.log(el.data("prod-name"));
    console.log(el.data("brand"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data()` method for retrive data-* attribute

```js
$(".something").each(function(){
console.log($(this).data()); // return object set of all data-*
console.log("product name: "+$(this).data('prod-name')) //return data-prod-name value
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something" data-prod-name="a" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id="137427">​A</div>​
<div class="something" data-prod-name="b" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id=​"128830">B</div>​
<div class="something" data-prod-name=​"c" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand="ABC" data-product-id=​"128827">​C</div>​
<div class="something" data-prod-name=​"d" data-category-name=​"b" data-brand=​"ABC" data-product-id=​"128824">​D</div>
```

Comment: It convert `category-name` to `categoryName`