# Get multiple attributes with .attr() to get both "id" and ":checked" from element using "this" | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

my question is very simple and doesn't seem to be around as often as setting or applying value in multiple cases.

Using `$(this)` how can I achieve to get multiple attributes from a single element using as the title informs simply `.attr()`.

```
$(this).attr('id', "checked") // Pseudo code
```

For the use to be stored in an array or variable for example. Thank you.

Comment: Something like `['id', 'checked'].map(a => $el.attr(a));` ?

Comment: @ixe Can you create a little demo?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/3877877](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/3877877) ... this could help you. if not, the answer from `aruna` is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you used will set the value to the attribute. Hence, you can use
something like `['id', 'checked'].map(a => $el.attr(a))` as mentioned by `lxe` in the comment or you can create a jQuery wrapper `attrs` as below.

To get the value of `checked` property, you can use `prop` as below instead of `attr`.

**Working snippet**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.attrs = function() {
    return Object.keys(arguments).map(k => $(this).prop(arguments[k]));
  };
  
  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
     globalCallback($(this).attrs('id', 'checked'));
  });
});

function globalCallback(attrs) {
  console.log(attrs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click the checkbox and see the console:
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /> Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /> Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" /> Checkbox 3
```

Comment: Where you've got `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` is it possible at all to make this get attributes of a single element using possibly `this`  compared to all checkbox elements? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yes, you can do. I just provided the above as a sample to loop all the checkboxes and inside the loop I have used `$(this)`. You can tell me which event you want to get the attributes or provide your html and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I mean inside the `each` I have used `$(this)` as `$(this).attrs('id', 'checked')` where `attrs` is a jQuery custom wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for the help. If I could ask you to once the radio/tick box is check, `this` gets and sends the id and checked true or false status to console like in your above example please.

Comment: Possibly without a button. Eg. Once the tick/radio box is ticked is the `.click` and not a button. Thank you.

Comment: You can click the checkbox and check the console and click the same checkbox again and check :-)

Comment: If you want this only for specific checkboxes, you can add a css class (like `testCss`) to them and use like this `$('input[type="checkbox"].testCss').click`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the example.

Comment: @Aruua Using your method above, how could you go about returning the variable value out to the global scope for example?

Comment: You can have a global method and call the method inside the click event by passing the attribute values as parameter.

Comment: Sorry to ask so much of you, but could I have an example of bringing the returning value out to the global scope please?

Comment: I have updated the answer and you can check the function `globalCallback` in global scope being called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, according to jQuery documentation:

> Get the value of **an attribute** for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Moreover your `$(this).attr('id', "checked")` code will set to the `id` attribute the `checked` value, since `attr` can be used to set values with exactly such syntax.

However you can create a helper methods like the one mentioned by lxe

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attributes using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) to create an object of attributes:

```js
// get all elements attributes, and convert them to array
var attributes = [].slice.call($('#v-box').get(0).attributes, 0);

// reduce the array to key value pairs
var object = attributes.reduce(function(r, attr) {
  r[attr.name] = attr.value;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="v-box" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend the jQuery function to accommodate what your looking for.
If you aren't interested in extending you could create a new function/ plugin as well

Here's an example:

```
(function($)
{
  var oldAttr = $.fn.attr;
  $.fn.attr = function() {
    var args= arguments[0];
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(args)=="[object Array]") {
      return [args.map((e=> oldAttr.apply(this, [e])))];
      //if you want to get a string you could just try `return args.map((e=> oldAttr.apply(this, [e])))`
    }
    return oldAttr.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/eztukwj9/