# Get class attribute list

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attributes

Let's say I have a div tag with class **sample**

```
<div class='sample' />
```

I'd like to get all attributes of **sample** class.

What is the right way to get class attributes of a DOM element?

Comment: By attributes you mean css properties?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/5192105