# Is there an error in the official release of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-events

I'am using the jquery-3.3.1.min.js version.
In my code:

```
$(function (){
  var div= $("#btn-space");
  div.find("button:eq(0)")
    .click(function(){
      var activeElement=$("#action")
        .find("div:first").attr();
    }) ;
});
```

This the error I get in the console error

```
Typerror: e is undefined  in 
jquery-3.3.1.min.js :2:63533
```

I think is from the `attr()` function. 
We can see that in the librairy on Line 2: column 63533

Comment: What exactly is it that you expect the call to `.attr()` with no argument to do?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing @Pointy

Comment: In general, for performance reasons jQuery does not include much in the way of validity tests or nice friendly exceptions. If you feed it garbage, you get an error but it's not necessarily easy to understand exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Their JS is minified. “e” is likely the argument name to `attr`, which expects a string of the attribute name. You didn’t provide one so the expected argument is undefined.

Comment: Why still use Jquery? For me, It's very easy to work with es6 & es7 rather than the Jquery.

Comment: My purpose is to obtain the attribute values of the button. This is why I did not supply any arguments. And print the variable value in the console log, or anything else.

Comment: `console.log(activeElement)`. I have forgetten to write it.

Comment: @Dilshan Realy ?? Are you saying that Es6 or Es7 deletes all the differents implementations in all browsers ?

Comment: @hackthatos My opinion. I'm using ReactJS library. ReactJS, Angular, Vue etc are the modern libraries and frameworks. Still jquery holds but  for me 'different implementations in all browsers' is not a fair reason to use Jquery. Only my opinion. Don't be angry with me :)

Comment: I should write this.                                                  `$(selector).attr(attributName)` to get the attribute value. Thanks

Comment: This will solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery



The answer to your question is that you must pass value to .attr()