# Show and set multiple attributes of an element using attr() in jQuery's attr() method [mainly style attribute]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning jQuery from W3school and stuck into a problem when I tried to show the multiple attributes of the **h3** tag given below using `attr()` method

```
<h3 class="test" style="color: white; background: coral">This is the <a href="#">H3 </a>
        tag and this will be our <strong style="color: teal">DEMO</strong> tag</h3> 

<button id="attr">Show Attribute</button>

<script>
$('#attr').click(function () {
                alert($('h3').attr('style'))
            })
<script>
```

How can I show **style,class** and other attributes of the `<h3>` ?

Second problem is that what if I want to change the style from the given one to `style="color: black; background: teal"` and `class='newClass'` using the SET `attr()`?

```
$('#setattr').click(function () {
                $('h3').attr('style:"color: black; background: lightpink')
            })
```

Doesn't seem to show any affect to the HTML. where `#setattr` is the id of the button.

Comment: `.attr` accepts an object for when you want to set multiple attributes at once https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: For getting all attributes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery